# get data from ksoap2 in android

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

please tell me how to retrieve multiple array of data in ksoap2 Result.
actually let me explain. 
i have a web service of employee search. when i search by name it gives me Multiple Records. one record contain name, last name, phone, address etc and there are total 30,40 records.

in other cases where we just recieve one output result we can use the following code in ksoap2

```
SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); //get response
String text = result.getProperty("response").toString();
```

This will return us the string from Response property but for only one record. now we have mutiple records how do we store each record. or how should be manipulate all the records.

Please friends guide me. :)

let me add some more details.. this is the xml i get as a result.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:searchResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:abcdwsdl">
     <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType=":[6]">
        <item xsi:type="xsd:string">success</item>
        <item xsi:type="xsd:string">Search results retrieved for *</item>
        <item xsi:type="xsd:">
           <item>
              <ad_id xsi:type="xsd:string">2</ad_id>
              <fname xsi:type="xsd:string">abcr</ad_text>
              <lname xsi:type="xsd:string">def</location>
              <phone xsi:type="xsd:float">123456</lati>
              <address xsi:type="xsd:float">America</longi>
           </item>
           <item>
              <ad_id xsi:type="xsd:string">12</ad_id>
              <fnamet xsi:type="xsd:string">test user</ad_text>
              <lname xsi:type="xsd:string">hello</location>
              <phone xsi:type="xsd:float">987654543</lati>
              <address xsi:type="xsd:float">England</longi>
           </item>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="xsd:int">2</item>
        <item xsi:type="xsd:int">0</item>
        <item xsi:type="xsd:int">0</item>
     </return>
  </ns1:searchResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256166/how-to-parse-a-list-of-objects-retrieved-with-ksoap-on-android

Comment: your helping material is actually for .net users

Comment: It shouldn't be very different. Anyway, as I see from the response you posted, you might try navigating to the 3rd item (`SoapObject o = result.getProperty(2)`) and from there cycling through the actual records.

Comment: i tried it but could not do it. actually now i m using Vectors so it is bringing me up the whole data. now i just have to parse all that records. one by one using Loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is The Answer:

[ksoap2 in android in Multiple Array Data Retrieving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976335/problem-in-ksoap2-in-android-in-mutiple-array-data-retreiving)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample code that parses an array of objects:

```
ArrayList<Pojo> pojos = null;
int totalCount = soapobject.getPropertyCount();
if (detailsTotal > 0 ) {
    pojos = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
    for (int detailCount = 0; detailCount < totalCount; detailCount++) {
        SoapObject pojoSoap = (SoapObject) soapobject.getProperty(detailCount);
        Pojo Pojo = new Pojo();
        Pojo.idNumber = pojoSoap.getProperty("idNumber").toString();
        Pojo.quantity =  pojoSoap.getProperty("quantity").toString();

        pojos.add(Pojo);
    }
}
```

Taken from [here](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
if (soapObject != null && soapObject.getPropertyCount() > 0) {
   for (int i = 0; i < soapObject.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
      SoapObject so = (SoapObject) soapObject.getProperty(i);
      MyObject obj = new MyObject();
      obj.setProperty1(so.getPropertyAsString("property1"));
      obj.setProperty2(so.getPropertyAsString("property2"));
      list.add(obj);
   }
}
```

That works for me.

Comment: Could you explain a bit?

Comment: I don't understand everything in that code. In fact, I have used that code for many projects, but I can mention something: first of all, you must check is soapObject contains any result, in order to extract values from it. Then, you use the getPropertyAsString method to retrieve a value by providing the name of the value you want to retrieve. However, you should check if the retrieved value is different from the text "anyType{}". That is because if the property you want to retrieve is null, then you will get a "anyType{}" string.

Comment: I suggest you to make a Log.i("SOAP OBJECT", soapObject.toString()) to see the values that you have before extract them from the soap object. That's all I can say. I'm not an expert on this topic. I'm just telling you what I've seen when I used Ksoap.